Time of flight measurement and calculation with TUSS4470
I want to measure time of flight (ToF) by using TUSS4470, I did a research and I noticed I need to measure the time between OUT4's START and STOP pulses, my question is which time we are referring to in the following image? We want to measure TIME-1 or TIME_2?

Reference of the image: https://e2e.ti.com/support/sensors-group/sensors/f/sensors-forum/936555/tuss4470-tof-resolution-and-application

Your question as written, does not involve electrical engineering.  Please update your question with the electrical information needed to address this issue.

itprorh66 Can you explain why this isn't considered electrical engineering? ... @Andromeda I'm not very familiar with ultrasound sensors but just by looking at the datasheet, the answer may vary on what your status registers look like that are set by the MCU. Looking at Figure 7-7, this gives us an indication of the processes of how the ultrasound measurement is sampled and some logical function that talks with the MCU. Table 7-11 and 7-15 may both give some hints for the times you're looking for.

Based on research that I did, for calculating the ToF with TUSS4470, we need to read the OUT4 pin and calculate TIME_1 as follows:

There is an register also that is called ToF configuration, in there we can set the voltage value in the comparator, for example, in my case it is set to 0.72V.
Reference: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slda058/slda058.pdf?ts=1729625274499&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTUSS4470

Good self-answered question :) Next time, please provide a link to your sources. It looks like you got this from the device's application note.

@ Colin yes, exactly, I will add it to my answer thanks. In fact I wrote the code in my MCU and it is perfectly working with high accuracy. It seems I can not accept my own answer, maybe can you please accept it to consider this question as resolved?

You're the only one who can "accept" the answer. I've already upvoted.
